# On consecutive superabundant numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

Define $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d$. A number $n>1$ is said to be [superabundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabundant_number) (SA) if it is an integer and $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}>\frac{\sigma(s)}{s}$ for every positive integer $s<n$. Let $n$ and $n'$ (where $n<n'$) denote consecutive SA numbers. Erdős and Alaoglu, demonstrated that $\frac{n'}{n}=1+ O\Big(\frac{(\log \log n)^2}{\log n}\Big).$ Does anyone know an *effective* form of this result ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean [Leonidas Alaoglu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonidas_Alaoglu) (rather than Alaogu). There is a paper *[On Highly Composite and Similar Numbers](https://doi.org/10.2307/1990319)* by Erdős and Aaloglu, which is also mentioned in the Wikipedia article on [Superabundant number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabundant_number).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, indeed. Thanks for the correction and the link. The result mentioned in the post is on page 454 of that paper...